# Do Azure Pipelines coerce types for and() and or()?

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline

I'm trying to detect whether a build should be published.  This depends on whether the branch is a feature branch AND (the name of the feature branch is stored in a group variable OR a parameter is set when the build is run).  I'm not getting the logic I would expect out of and() and or(), and it appears to be related to type coercion.

```
    value: $[ startsWith(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature') ]
  - name: autoPublishBranches
    value: $[ contains(variables['PublishBranches'], variables['build.sourceBranch']) ]
  - name: publishFeature
    value: $[ and( variables.featureBuild, or( variables.autoPublishBranches, ${{ parameters.manualPublishBranch }} ))]
  - name: publishToDocker
    value: $[ or( variables.autoPublishNonFeature, and( variables.featureBuild, or( variables.autoPublishBranches, ${{ parameters.manualPublishBranch }} ))) ]

  - name: debugTest
    value: $[ or('false', and('False', or('True', False))) ]

  - name: TruthTable_Or_1
    value: $[ or('false', 'false') ]
  - name: TruthTable_Or_2
    value: $[ or('false', 'true') ]
  - name: TruthTable_Or_3
    value: $[ or('true', 'false') ]
  - name: TruthTable_Or_4
    value: $[ or('true', 'true') ]
  - name: TruthTable_Or_5
    value: $[ or('False', 'false') ]
  - name: TruthTable_Or_6
    value: $[ or('True', 'true') ]
  - name: TruthTable_Or_7
    value: $[ or(False, False) ]
  - name: TruthTable_Or_8
    value: $[ or(True, True) ]
  - name: TruthTable_Or_9
    value: $[ or('False', 'False') ]
  - name: TruthTable_Or_10
    value: $[ or('True', 'True') ]
  - name: TruthTable_Or_11
    value: $[ or('False', False) ]
  - name: TruthTable_Or_12
    value: $[ or('True', True) ]
```

Produces

```
  featureBuild:
    Parsing expression: <startsWith(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature')>
    Evaluating: startsWith(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature')
    Expanded: startsWith('refs/heads/user/dreuss/deploy_based_on_group_variable', 'refs/heads/feature')
    Result: 'False'
  autoPublishBranches:
    Parsing expression: <contains(variables['PublishBranches'], variables['build.sourceBranch'])>
    Evaluating: contains(variables['PublishBranches'], variables['build.sourceBranch'])
    Expanded: contains('refs/heads/user/dreuss/deploy_based_on_group_variable,refs/heads/master', 'refs/heads/user/dreuss/deploy_based_on_group_variable')
    Result: 'True'
  publishFeature:
    Parsing expression: <and( variables.featureBuild, or( variables.autoPublishBranches, False ))>
    Evaluating: and(variables['featureBuild'], or(variables['autoPublishBranches'], False))
    Expanded: and('False', or('True', False))
    Result: 'True'
  publishToDocker:
    Parsing expression: <or( variables.autoPublishNonFeature, and( variables.featureBuild, or( variables.autoPublishBranches, False )))>
    Evaluating: or(variables['autoPublishNonFeature'], and(variables['featureBuild'], or(variables['autoPublishBranches'], False)))
    Expanded: or('false', and(variables['featureBuild'], or(variables['autoPublishBranches'], False)))
    Result: 'True'
  debugTest:
    Parsing expression: <or('false', and('False', or('True', False)))>
    Evaluating: or('false', and('False', or('True', False)))
    Expanded: or('false', and('False', or('True', False)))
    Result: 'True'
  TruthTable_Or_1:
    Parsing expression: <or('false', 'false')>
    Evaluating: or('false', 'false')
    Expanded: or('false', 'false')
    Result: 'True'
  TruthTable_Or_2:
    Parsing expression: <or('false', 'true')>
    Evaluating: or('false', 'true')
    Expanded: or('false', 'true')
    Result: 'True'
  TruthTable_Or_3:
    Parsing expression: <or('true', 'false')>
    Evaluating: or('true', 'false')
    Expanded: or('true', 'false')
    Result: 'True'
  TruthTable_Or_4:
    Parsing expression: <or('true', 'true')>
    Evaluating: or('true', 'true')
    Expanded: or('true', 'true')
    Result: 'True'
  TruthTable_Or_5:
    Evaluating: or('false', 'false')
    Expanded: or('false', 'false')
    Result: 'True'
  TruthTable_Or_6:
    Evaluating: or('true', 'true')
    Expanded: or('true', 'true')
    Result: 'True'
  TruthTable_Or_7:
    Parsing expression: <or(False, False)>
    Evaluating: or(False, False)
    Expanded: or(False, False)
    Result: 'False'
  TruthTable_Or_8:
    Parsing expression: <or(True, True)>
    Evaluating: or(True, True)
    Expanded: or(True, True)
    Result: 'True'
  TruthTable_Or_9:
    Evaluating: or('false', 'false')
    Expanded: or('false', 'false')
    Result: 'True'
  TruthTable_Or_10:
    Evaluating: or('true', 'true')
    Expanded: or('true', 'true')
    Result: 'True'
  TruthTable_Or_11:
    Parsing expression: <or('False', False)>
    Evaluating: or('False', False)
    Expanded: or('False', False)
    Result: 'True'
  TruthTable_Or_12:
    Parsing expression: <or('True', True)>
    Evaluating: or('True', True)
    Expanded: or('True', True)
    Result: 'True'
```

It's unclear why sometimes it evaluates to 'false' vs 'False', and per the docs and() and or() should coerce types, but it doesn't appear they are (or I'm syntaxing incorrectly).  I guess I could use eq() and see if that coerces, but that's messier than I'd like this to be.

Answer (score 0):

[Boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#boolean) : `True` and `False` are boolean literal expressions.

[String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#string) : Must be single-quoted. For example: `'false'`, `'true'`.

non-null string, it will evaluate to be 1(True boolean) when calculating. True and False are literally the values `1` and `0`.

The result of a logical or Boolean expression is considered true if it evaluates to `1` and false if it evaluates to `0`.

Here we take the expression: `<or('false', and('False', or('True', False)))>`  as an example.  We can think of it as `<or(1, and(1, or(1, 0)))>`, the result is `1` -> `True`.